# GPUdate PS Commandlet

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I'm having an issue with this script. For some reason, it was working previously and now it is not. It is now returning with:

> Invoke-GPUpdate : The term 'Invoke-GPUpdate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

`Write-Host "Refreshing Group Policies on the local machine......."`

`Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $computer -RandomDelayInMinutes 0 -force ForegroundColor Cyan`

`Start-Sleep -s 20`

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `gpupdate /force` which should be available on every Windows version _currently_ in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Invoke-GPUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/invoke-gpupdate?view=windowsserver2019-ps#notes) is part of the [`GroupPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) module. `GroupPolicy` is not available by default, but is included with RSAT Tools. What likely happened is a major update to Windows occurred and in this case, if RSAT Tools isn't installed as a Windows Feature (it is only available as a "Feature on Demand" beginning with the `Windows 10 October 2018 Update`, which is build 17763), it will get removed during the update and needs to be re-installed.

This technically happens with the feature as well I believe, as RSAT Tools is still linked to specific versions of Windows, but the upgrade process will re-install the feature if it was already present.

### Installing `GroupPolicy` RSAT Tools as a feature with Windows PowerShell

**If you have Windows 1809 or newer**, you can install as a feature using the following command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name 'Rsat.GroupPolicy.*' -Online | Where-Object { $_.State -ne 'Installed' } | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

You can do the same with other RSAT Tools as well (the features are modularized per their functionality). To enumerate all of them:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT*
```

Once again, this requires Windows 1809 or newer or the features will be unavailable. You'll have to install it [by using the MSU provided by Microsoft for your Windows version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520).